# How can I select results from another table based on ids from single column?

Tags: sql

Hi i need get this to string. I have 2 tables like this:

users
id  - name  - sport
1  -  John  - 1,2,3
2  -  Peter - 2,3

sports

id - sport
1 -  squash
2 -  football
3  - basketball

Expected result in string:
[name] => John
[sport] => squash, football, basketball

[name] => Peter
[sport] => football, basketball

Comment: That's a awkward DB design. Consider normalizing your table. BTW, which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Do some research on the concept of 'many-to-many' relationships. That will require you to introduce a link table which allows you to easily retrieve the results in the format you wish.

Comment: I use Mysql sorry I was new. i still learning it. if u have some better idea about design write it please

Answer (score 1):

This is a `many to many` relationship. Moreover, your `users` table is not in 1NF even. Read more about `M:M` relationship [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) (OR) [Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/create-relationships-for-a-new-database-RZ101772998.aspx?section=9).

Have your tables structured like

```
users (Here make `id` as primary key)

id - name 
1 - John 
2 - Peter

usersport (Here make `id` as foriegn key referencing to `users` `id` column)

id sportnum
1  1
1  2
1  3
2  2
2  3


sportsdetail

id - sport
1 - squash
2 - football
3 - basketball
```

Now, to get your desired result you can make a query like below

```
select u.name,sd.sport
from users u
inner join usersport us on u.id = us.id
inner join sportsdetail sd on us.sportnum = sd.id
```